# Find the work done in force field

Tags: integration, line-integrals

A unit particle is moved in an anticlockwise manner round a circle with center $(0,0,4)$ and radius  2 in the plane $z=4$ in a force field defined as $F=(xy+z)\boldsymbol{\hat{i}} + (2x+y)\boldsymbol{\hat{j}}+(x+y+z)\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$. Find the work done. How can I solve it?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: This is a line integral. You should start by parametrizing your curve. $r=\gamma(t)$.

Comment: this is a homework. a question ı dont know about this integral.ım studying and Im trying to learn.ı did nothing :/,I hope, you are lead to me.

Comment: In that case, the first thing you should try is a revision of the material leading up to this homework. I would expect that there are several examples of how to approach this exercise in there.

Comment: exactly there is not example like this.there are several examples,but easy examles.not work for this question.. why ım here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametrized curve you should use is $\gamma(t) = (2\cos t, 2\sin t, 4)$, with $\gamma'(t) = (-2\sin t, 2\cos t, 0)$ and $t \in [0,2\pi]$. Furthermore ${\bf{F}}(\gamma(t)) = (4\sin t \cos t +4, 4\cos t + 2\sin t, 2\cos t + 2\sin t + 4)$
So, you have to calculate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (-8\sin^{2}t\cos t-8\sin t+8\cos^{2}t+4\sin t\cos t) dt$$

Comment: thank you so much sir...

Comment: Just to state it explicitly, in general (as is done here) you always want to integrate $\boldsymbol{F}(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)$ wrt $t$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sometimes the line integral is even defined like this!